# Meaning of Φ : Y → X

Tags: calculus, notation, terminology, symbolic-computation

I am reading the book "Advances in Intelligent Systems and Computing" and I cannot understand a paragraph.

> Parametric approaches include the classical SOM and its probabilistic
> counterpart generative topographic mapping (GTM) [3]. Both approaches
> are based on a low dimensional latent space, the regular SOM grid or
> the real plane with a probability distribution peaked at regular grid
> positions for GTM. These points are associated to high dimensional
> coordinates in the data space, the parameters of the mapping, called
> prototypes wj, which are directly assigned to grid positions by means
> of the index in case of SOM, or which are images of a parameterized
> generalized linear function Φ : Y → X in case of GTM.

What is the meaning of Φ : Y → X  in this context? In addition, what is "high dimensional coordinates in the data space"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\Phi$ is a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) that maps from set $Y$ to set $X$

Comment: ‘High dimensional coordinates’ here refers to measurements with a lot of entries, for example image color per pixel. $\Phi$ provides a dimensional reduction.

Comment: Thank you, J.W.Tanner and a rural reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [rural reader](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/874661/a-rural-reader) pointed out in a comment, that ‘High dimensional coordinates’ here refers to measurements with a lot of entries, for example image color per pixel. Φ
provides a dimensional reduction. As [J.W.Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615567/j-w-tanner) pointed out in a comment, Φ is a function that maps from set Y to set X.